# AppSecret with Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

Moving question from CodePlex to Stackoverflow where this really belongs.

I see that facebook generates an AppId and an AppSecret. In the sample provided, AppId is baked into the code however there is no mention of using AppSecret. Shouldn't it be specified some where in the code to sign requests? What am I missing?

Thanks,

WP7Noob

Response from DevTheo

The way we are getting the Access Token gets around needing the secret. Once you have an access token, you can pretty much do everything you need to do. You can, of course, add it to the creation of the FacebookApp (but I'm pretty sure with the way we are doing things you don't need the secret).

Jay

Comment: What I am unable to understand is the scenarios in which AppSecret is needed and scenarios in which it is not? Having that understanding will really convince that I am doing the right thing. What is so different about Android/iPhone SDKs that they require AppSecret?

Answer (score 0):

We don't use the app secret in the WP7 authentication process because we don't think it is best practice to put the secret with your app. You should only use the app secret on your server where it is secure. I am not sure why the iOS or Android SDKs use them because that is really against Facebook's own best practices. (And yes, I realize the irony of Facebook breaking their own guidelines, but they do it all the time).

Additionally, the way that OAuth works on a WAP device (as DevTheo pointed out) we dont need the secret to get the access token.

This being said, you are correct that you can't verify the authenticity of the token when you receive it. But that really isn't a problem. If somebody spoofs a token, it wont work.